# Usually two different meanings

Tags: word, pattern

I'm looking for a 6-letter word.

---

### 837195260

### 402368571

### 154093682

### 683407251

### 78396514

### 57364028

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 6-letter word is:

> **DIGITS** - a word which, as per the title, usually has two different meanings: (i) numbers, and (ii) fingers, thumbs or toes.
>
>  Here, it's the numbers angle that is most relevant...

Take a look at each of the six strings of numbers in turn...

> Each of these comprises a seemingly random arrangement of the digits 0-9, once each, but with one or two of them missing. The missing digits are, in turn:
>
>  4; 9; 7; 9; 2 and 0; 1 and 9.
>
>  If we convert these numbers into letters via A1Z26, concatenating '2 and 0' as 20 and '1 and 9' as 19, these represent the letters **DIGITS**, which must surely be the hidden answer.

Comment: I had a suspicion this would get solved pretty fast, but not this fast :D Well done!